# Android detect (Call Waiting) second incoming call state

Tags: java, android

Hello i am trying to detect **call waiting state** in android I successfully detecting android call events like `CALL_STATE_RINGING`, `CALL_STATE_IDLE` and its working fine but I need to detect 2nd incoming call while there is another active call, for example, 1st call is active on phone and when some other trying to call on this number let 1st number be ABC and second incoming number be XYZ so when ABC call connected to check if ABC is already active then disconnect 1st active call and pick 2nd incoming call.

**PhonecallReceiver**

```
public abstract class PhonecallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    //The receiver will be recreated whenever android feels like it.  We need a static variable to remember data between instantiations

    private static int lastState = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;
    private static Date callStartTime;
    private static boolean isIncoming;
    private static String savedNumber;  //because the passed incoming is only valid in ringing


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {




        //We listen to two intents.  The new outgoing call only tells us of an outgoing call.  We use it to get the number.
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL")) {
            savedNumber = intent.getExtras().getString("android.intent.extra.PHONE_NUMBER");
        }
        else{
            String stateStr = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
            String number = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
            Toast.makeText(context, number, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            int state = 0;
            if(stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)){
                state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;
                Toast.makeText(context, "CALL_STATE_IDLE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if(stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)){
                state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK;
                Toast.makeText(context, "CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if(stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)){
                state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING;
                Toast.makeText(context, "CALL_STATE_RINGING", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


            onCallStateChanged(context, state, number);
        }
    }

    //Derived classes should override these to respond to specific events of interest
    protected abstract void onIncomingCallReceived(Context ctx, String number, Date start);
    protected abstract void onIncomingCallAnswered(Context ctx, String number, Date start);
    protected abstract void onIncomingCallEnded(Context ctx, String number, Date start, Date end);

    protected abstract void onOutgoingCallStarted(Context ctx, String number, Date start);
    protected abstract void onOutgoingCallEnded(Context ctx, String number, Date start, Date end);

    protected abstract void onMissedCall(Context ctx, String number, Date start);

    //Deals with actual events

    //Incoming call-  goes from IDLE to RINGING when it rings, to OFFHOOK when it's answered, to IDLE when its hung up
    //Outgoing call-  goes from IDLE to OFFHOOK when it dials out, to IDLE when hung up
    public void onCallStateChanged(Context context, int state, String number) {
        if(lastState == state){
            //No change, debounce extras
            return;
        }
        switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                isIncoming = true;
                callStartTime = new Date();
                savedNumber = number;
                onIncomingCallReceived(context, number, callStartTime);
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                //Transition of ringing->offhook are pickups of incoming calls.  Nothing done on them
                if(lastState != TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING){
                    isIncoming = false;
                    callStartTime = new Date();
                    onOutgoingCallStarted(context, savedNumber, callStartTime);
                }
                else
                {
                    isIncoming = true;
                    callStartTime = new Date();
                    onIncomingCallAnswered(context, savedNumber, callStartTime);
                }

                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                //Went to idle-  this is the end of a call.  What type depends on previous state(s)
                if(lastState == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING){
                    //Ring but no pickup-  a miss
                    onMissedCall(context, savedNumber, callStartTime);
                }
                else if(isIncoming){
                    onIncomingCallEnded(context, savedNumber, callStartTime, new Date());
                }
                else{
                    onOutgoingCallEnded(context, savedNumber, callStartTime, new Date());
                }
                break;
        }
        lastState = state;
    }
}
```

**CallReceiver**

```
public class CallReceiver extends PhonecallReceiver {

    @Override
    protected void onIncomingCallReceived(Context ctx, String number, Date start)
    {


        Toast.makeText(ctx, "Call Recicevd", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onIncomingCallAnswered(Context ctx, String number, Date start)
    {
        Toast.makeText(ctx, "Call CallAnswered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onIncomingCallEnded(Context ctx, String number, Date start, Date end)
    {
        Toast.makeText(ctx, "Call onIncomingCallEnded", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onOutgoingCallStarted(Context ctx, String number, Date start)
    {
        Toast.makeText(ctx, "Call onOutgoingCallStarted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onOutgoingCallEnded(Context ctx, String number, Date start, Date end)
    {
        Toast.makeText(ctx, "Call onOutgoingCallEnded", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMissedCall(Context ctx, String number, Date start)
    {
        Toast.makeText(ctx, "Call onMissedCall", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have system permission for you app, you can try to add permission in AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PRECISE_PHONE_STATE" />
```

```
public class SystemTelephonyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        if ((intent != null) && (intent.getAction() != null))
        {
            String extraState = null;
            String extraIncomingNumber = null;
            int foregroundState = -3;
            int backgroundState = -3;
            int ringingState = -3;
            switch (intent.getAction())
            {
                case TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED:
                {
                    extraState = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
                    extraIncomingNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);

                    if (extraState != null)
                    {
                        switch (extraState)
                        {
                            case "IDLE":
                            {
                                Log.d("SystemTelephony", "extraState = " + "IDLE");
                                Log.d("SystemTelephony", "extraIncomingNumber = " + extraIncomingNumber);
                            }
                            break;
                            case "OFFHOOK":
                            {
                                Log.d("SystemTelephony", "extraState = " + "OFFHOOK");
                                Log.d("SystemTelephony", "extraIncomingNumber = " + extraIncomingNumber);
                            }
                            break;
                            case "RINGING":
                            {
                                Log.d("SystemTelephony", "extraState = " + "RINGING");
                                Log.d("SystemTelephony", "extraIncomingNumber = " + extraIncomingNumber);
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
                case "android.intent.action.PRECISE_CALL_STATE":
                {

                    foregroundState = intent.getIntExtra("foreground_state", -2);
                    backgroundState = intent.getIntExtra("background_state", -2);
                    ringingState = intent.getIntExtra("ringing_state", -2);

                    switch (foregroundState)
                    {
                        case -1:
                            Log.d("SystemTelephony", "foregroundState = " + "PRECISE_CALL_STATE_NOT_VALID");
                            break;
                        case 0:
                            Log.d("SystemTelephony", "foregroundState = " + "PRECISE_CALL_STATE_IDLE");
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            Log.d("SystemTelephony", "foregroundState = " + "PRECISE_CALL_STATE_ACTIVE");
                              PhoneCallManager.getInstance(CustomApplication.getInstance()).onCallAnswer();
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            Log.d("SystemTelephony", "foregroundState = " + "PRECISE_CALL_STATE_HOLDING");
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            Log.d("SystemTelephony", "foregroundState = " + "PRECISE_CALL_STATE_DIALING");
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            Log.d("SystemTelephony", "foregroundState = " + "PRECISE_CALL_STATE_ALERTING");
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            Log.d("SystemTelephony", "foregroundState = " + "PRECISE_CALL_STATE_INCOMING");
                            break;
                        case 6:
                            Log.d("SystemTelephony", "foregroundState = " + "PRECISE_CALL_STATE_WAITING");
                            break;
                        case 7:
                            Log.d("SystemTelephony", "foregroundState = " + "PRECISE_CALL_STATE_DISCONNECTED");
                            break;
                        case 8:
                            Log.d("SystemTelephony", "foregroundState = " + "PRECISE_CALL_STATE_DISCONNECTING");
                            break;
                    }

                    switch (backgroundState)
                    {
                        case -1:
                            Log.d("SystemTelephony", "backgroundState = " + "PRECISE_CALL_STATE_NOT_VALID");
                            break;
                        case 0:
                            Log.d("SystemTelephony", "backgroundState = " + "PRECISE_CALL_STATE_IDLE");
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            Log.d("SystemTelephony", "backgroundState = " + "PRECISE_CALL_STATE_ACTIVE");
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            Log.d("SystemTelephony", "backgroundState = " + "PRECISE_CALL_STATE_HOLDING");
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            Log.d("SystemTelephony", "backgroundState = " + "PRECISE_CALL_STATE_DIALING");
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            Log.d("SystemTelephony", "backgroundState = " + "PRECISE_CALL_STATE_ALERTING");
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            Log.d("SystemTelephony", "backgroundState = " + "PRECISE_CALL_STATE_INCOMING");
                            break;
                        case 6:
                            Log.d("SystemTelephony", "backgroundState = " + "PRECISE_CALL_STATE_WAITING");
                            break;
                        case 7:
                            Log.d("SystemTelephony", "backgroundState = " + "PRECISE_CALL_STATE_DISCONNECTED");
                            break;
                        case 8:
                            Log.d("SystemTelephony", "backgroundState = " + "PRECISE_CALL_STATE_DISCONNECTING");
                            break;
                    }

                    switch (ringingState)
                    {
                        case -1:
                            Log.d("SystemTelephony", "ringingState = " + "PRECISE_CALL_STATE_NOT_VALID");
                            break;
                        case 0:
                            Log.d("SystemTelephony", "ringingState = " + "PRECISE_CALL_STATE_IDLE");
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            Log.d("SystemTelephony", "ringingState = " + "PRECISE_CALL_STATE_ACTIVE");
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            Log.d("SystemTelephony", "ringingState = " + "PRECISE_CALL_STATE_HOLDING");
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            Log.d("SystemTelephony", "ringingState = " + "PRECISE_CALL_STATE_DIALING");
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            Log.d("SystemTelephony", "ringingState = " + "PRECISE_CALL_STATE_ALERTING");
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            Log.d("SystemTelephony", "ringingState = " + "PRECISE_CALL_STATE_INCOMING");
                            break;
                        case 6:
                            Log.d("SystemTelephony", "ringingState = " + "PRECISE_CALL_STATE_WAITING");
                            break;
                        case 7:
                            Log.d("SystemTelephony", "ringingState = " + "PRECISE_CALL_STATE_DISCONNECTED");
                            break;
                        case 8:
                            Log.d("SystemTelephony", "ringingState = " + "PRECISE_CALL_STATE_DISCONNECTING");
                            break;
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In Android R we have open permisison for `READ_PRECISE_PHONE_STATE`, and also for special-use applications such as dialers, carrier applications, or ims applications, you can have a try.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly I might put here on SO about my little project on detecting all I can with the 3 states (did everything I could with 1 and 2 calls already, just missing 3 or more calls now, which is the same case), but you need to check if there is any call already in CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK. Would happen like this:

RINGING (ABC) --> OFFHOOK (ABC) --> RINGING (XYZ) == 2nd call is waiting

So you need to check if there is another call with the state OFFHOOK --> you need to store the last state for each call in order to do this, I guess - at least that's how I'm doing it to detect various things, like call lost, waiting, finished, ..... The list you could put it on SharedPreferences or something, or let the class instanciated (in memory) like I did.

If I didn't explain right, I can try again, just say!